# Could not find an overload for 'logInWithPermissions' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: ios, swift

I'm receiving this error message in response to the following code. I understand this typically arises when a type needs to be explicitly converted, but the permissions array here is explicitly defined as an `AnyObject[]?`, the correct argument type.

Edit: Using Facebook Login for Parse (documentation:https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-setup/iOS)

```
let permissions: AnyObject[]? = ["email", "user_education_history", "publish_stream", "publish_actions"]

PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: { (user: PFUser, error: NSError) in
        if (!user) {
            println("Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
        } else if (user.isNew) {
            println("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
        } else {
            println("User logged in through Facebook!");
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Could you post your error message?

Comment: The error message is the title, I believe

Comment: What happens if `permissions` is `String[]` (not optional and not AnyObject, but mostly not optional)?

Comment: @matt, returns the same error using `let permissions: String[] ...`

Comment: If you position your cursor after the `(` on `loginWithPermissions(` and press `escape`, what does autocomplete show for the method signature? It probably needs to be something other than `AnyObject[]`.

Comment: What happens if you write the block like this: `{user, error in...`? I'm thinking maybe the block is not explicitly typed at the other end so you have to let the types be inferred...?

Comment: @gwcoffey, doing what you suggested yields `String` in the autocomplete, although replacing the argument with a string literal returns the same error. Note that the Objective-C version of this code takes an `NSArray`. 
@matt I'm nearly certain the issue here is with the first argument, but thanks.

Comment: @Brandon have you tried making the arguments to the blocks optional, e.g. PFUser? and NSError? – non-optional types like PFUser can't possibly be nil, so your first check if (!user) wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Sorry for all the "shot in the dark" nonsense, but did you try `as NSArray`? This will all feel very confusing for a while...

Comment: @matt - sorry, you were right! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the second argument, the block. The two arguments are typed as `PFUser` and `NSError`, but they should be optional types (because those values are coming from Objective-C and can be nil). You can fix it by excluding the types from your closure and letting the compiler infer them:

```
PFFacebookUtils.logInWithPermissions(permissions, block: { user, error in ... })
```